# React Native Expo localhost request not work on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, react-native, expo

I simply use "fetch" to send GET request to my localhost API but it shows network fail. It works to send GET request to other non localhost website.

I would like to know the way to access my localhost API. the environment is that I use NativeBase and run it by Expo on android emulator. and the Expo connection is LAN.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you must use the ip instead of localhost:

for windows: ipconfig (IP ADDRESS)
for mac: networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi (IP ADDRESS)

the request would be like that:

```
axios.get('http://192.168.0.34')
```

I recommend using axios for react native

Answer (score 1):

You can get an IP address at runtime using `expo-constants` module's manifest.

If you did not install this module, Run `expo install expo-constants`

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const { manifest } = Constants;
...
const uri = `http://${manifest.debuggerHost
  .split(`:`)
  .shift()
  .concat(`:1000`)}`; // Switch to the port you use. ex)localhost:3000 => .concat(`:3000`)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether your solution works. In my understanding, you are trying to set the URI as an constant.

Comment: my expo cannot be functional after installing expo-constants. it's not able to run on android now: Unable to resolve “expo-constants” from “node_modules\expo-asset\src\Asset.js”

Comment: Did you ejected the Expo?

Comment: I'm just putting it in the constant so that it's easy to use. You don't have to put it if you don't want it.

Comment: Since the emulator did not recognize localhost, it simply took the IP value and created the address.

Answer (score 0):

accidently i found a way. go windows security > firewall and network protection and close the three of them. Then you can do two things.
1- go to cmd and write ipconfig,  take the ip
2- on react native project :
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const { manifest } = Constants;
const uri = `ws://${manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift()}:3000`;
this way you can take your ip dynamicly. (switch your port to do you want)

Answer (score 0):

localhost or 127.0.01 didn't work for me.

```
 import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const { manifest } = Constants;
const uri = `http://${manifest.debuggerHost
  .split(`:`)
  .shift()
  .concat(`:1000`)}`;
```

this one worked